# PreCalculus Domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the domain of $(x-3)^{1/2}\;?$

The domain would be $x>3$ wouldn't it? Because the graph doesn't exist until after the point $(3,0)$

Answer (score 4):

We must have that $x - 3\geq 0 \iff x \geq 3$.

So $3$ is indeed *included* in the domain, since $\sqrt{3-3} = \sqrt 0 = 0$.

Thus the domain is $[3, +\infty):\;$ all real numbers $x$ for which $x\geq 3$.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, Maxwell.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x-3}$ is defined (on the real line) only for $x-3\geqslant0 \iff x\geqslant3$, so $$\rm{dom}(f)=[3,\infty).$$

(Also, remember that infinity is not a real number, so we have to exclude it from our interval).

So, you're *almost* right. It's just that you have to include $3$ in your domain, since $\sqrt{3-3}=0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is well-defined in the reals.